# Iterator should yied error message Ruby, rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm supposed to return odd values from an array, but I keep getting failure in rspec if I pass this

```
odd_elements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) { |x| x**2 }
```

My code looks like this

```
def odd_elements(array)
    array.values_at(* array.each_index.select {|i| i.odd?})
end
```

Code in rspec is:

```
describe 'Odd iterator' do
 context 'should yield' do
  subject(:res) { odd_elements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) { |x| x**2 } }
  it { is_expected.to be_an_instance_of Array }
  it { expect(res.size).to be 3 }
  it { expect(res[0]).to be 4 }
  it { expect(res[1]).to be 16 }
  it { expect(res[2]).to be 36 }
 end
end
```

Error I get is `Odd iterator should yield should get 4` (and the same for other two numbers, 16 and 36 respectively).

Could someone please tell me, why the code in curly brackets doesn't get executed before being passed to the `odd_modules`?

Comment: Hint: the test case even is named "Odd iterator should `yield`". Well, does it?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you could write `is_odd = [false, true].cycle; array.select { is_odd.next }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you execute the block if `odd_elements` is defined by you.

```
def odd_elements(array)
  array.map! { |item| yield item } if block_given?
  array.select(&:odd?)
end
```

output

```
2.3.1 :088 > odd_elements([1,2,3,4])
 => [1, 3] 
2.3.1 :088 > odd_elements([1,2,3,4]) { |x| x + 1 }
 => [3, 5]
```